# Limiting one appointment per user

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm trying to make it so users are only able to schedule one appointment. Here I am modifying the save method. What I am trying to figure out is how to see if that user already has an appointment.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if Appointment.objects.filter(owner=user_pk).exists() and not self.pk:
        # if you'll not check for self.pk
        # then error will also raised in update of exists model
        raise ValidationError('You have already scheduled an appointment.')
    return super(Appointment, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

In my views.py I already have something that will raise an error if an appointment with that user already exists. But i'm thinking this is not enough and that there should be something at the model level.

```
appointments = Appointment.objects.filter(owner=request.user)
    if appointments.exists():
        raise PermissionDenied('You have already scheduled an appointment.')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than having your view handle that logic,I would change the database relation to a [`OneToOneField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/).  Have the field be nullable, and therefore you can rely on your django's db module to maintain relational integrity with this field

As described in the source code:

```
A OneToOneField is essentially the same as a ForeignKey, with the exception
that it always carries a "unique" constraint with it and the reverse
relation always returns the object pointed to (since there will only ever
be one), rather than returning a list.
```

Comment: Ah yes that definitely sounds like the correct way to do it!

Answer (score 1):

The `self` object has the `owner` attribute set to the current user, so you can use `self.owner` to access it:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if Appointment.objects.filter(owner=self.owner).exists() and not self.pk:
    ...
```